# Image results in 403 on PHP page

Tags: php, apache

Users on my websites can create folders under their userId. Once the folder is created they can move images from their userId folder to any other folder they created.

The image gets moved to the correct folder and everything works perfectly! After 30/40 minutes when I refresh the page, the image results into a 403 (search permissions are missing on a component of the path). So I checked all the folders starting from root, and every folder had the same rights (755). Once I opened the folder where the image was stored, the 403 got away. And everything was fine again for 30/40 minutes and the process started all over again.

**NOTE:** After some debgugging I found out that after 30 minutes the owner of the file gets changed from "staff" to "root". But after opening the folder (even on my webbrowser) the image works again, for 30 minutes...

Comment: Have you checked crontab or scheduled jobs?

Comment: I don't have acces to the apache server unfortunately. I did ask my hosting service to take a look at the VHOST. No reply's yet.